# How do I delete the other object?

Tags: materials, objects, 3d-view, edit-mode

I'm very new to Blender. I have downloaded a model of a pair of shoes. I want to delete the other shoe so that I can position it accordingly, but it isn't deleting.

I tried deleting this in the *Edit Mode* but it doesn't show up in this mode. How can I delete one shoe from the pair?

[image]

Comment: Oh I won't lie by saying "If I have a million dollar, I would literally give that to you" but I could send you $5 it is the same price of the addon subscription from which I downloaded this shoe...if you want you can leave your paypal email, I'll send it over

Comment: no it's ok...  ;)

Comment: hey I'm not just saying I can seriously send this right now, I wanna appreciate how you helped me in just minutes...cuz Im having a project going on which should be completed by tomorrow and I thought that I couldn't be able to finish this by that day but you just helped. I could even send $10 if you want...

Comment: you'll hire me when you'll need a freelance   ;)

Comment: you mean hiring you over here at Blenders exchange ?

Comment: check my youtube channel (blender moonboots) and if you ever need a freelance you can contact me

Comment: Sure bro I will deffinately do and I do respect your decision too...btw what's your name ?

Comment: Alright bro and again thank you for the help and I'll keep you in mind whenever I got a big project I'll hit you up ;)

Comment: ok good luck!  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hidden the other shoe in *Edit* mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide